# chat bubbles showing earlier in the chat iOS

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, swift

I am developing a chat based application for iOS. We are having a problem with the way the chat bubbles are displayed in the chat screen. Sometimes, the chat bubbles are getting placed earlier in the chat screen, and the user has to scroll up to read the message.

My developer says that the way he did it is that the chat bubbles are displayed based on the delivery time to the server, so if a message is delivered to the server first it will be shown earlier in the chat.

I would like the messages to be displayed one under the other -like in Whats App- and not have messages being placed earlier in the chat. The last message to show in the chat screen should be placed at the bottom of the list.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the database every message should have an ID. Sort it that way and not after the date.

Comment: Is this what you searched for?

Comment: I think your suggestion will solve the problem. At the moment the messages are showing in the chat screen based on the delivery time to the server. If a message gets to the server first but is delivered to my chat screen later because of server delays, it will be placed before other messages which already show up in my chat screen. If we use the ID instead of the timestamp we should solve this problem. Thanks :)